# How to modify the Registry with VBA?

Tags: vba, printing, registry

How to modify the registry for Print Dialog. I want to set the default value name with "Microsoft Print to PDF" for Print Dialog (Please find the current value of default name in next images-> "Send To OneNote 16" ):
[image]

[image]

Comment: Always helps to mention what happens when you run any code you've included in your question...

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted answer, instead of adding it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEM SOLVED:
I used next code:

```
Sub Macro1()

  Dim myWS As Object
  Set myWS = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Dim name As String, value As String, stype As String
  'a = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers"
  name = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\Defaults\{D3FCCD56-3DC5-4708-9EC8-8BD5ECA07FC2}\"
  value = "Microsoft Print to PDF"
  stype = "REG_SZ"
  myWS.RegWrite name, value, stype

End Sub
```

Please find the result in next images, after Macro1() was executed:

[image]
[image]